# Hide the expander on the next page of carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, expander

I combined the code from two different scripts as shown below:

Dynamic Carousel: https://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/dynamic-carousel/
Expanding Image Preview: http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Thumbnail-Grid-with-Expanding-Image-Preview-Using-jQuery.html

I want use this code actually (https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/), but the code is not working at here :(

Basically my problem is the expander cannot close when I click the "Next" button to the next page. You can try the code below and you will see what is my problem.

So what I want is the expander/image preview will close automatically when scroll to the next page of carousel. Please ask if my explanation is not clear enough, hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
(function(global, $){
  $('.gallery-items').imagelistexpander({
    prefix: "gallery-"
  });
})(this, jQuery)


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slidewrap').carousel({
    slider: '.slider',
    slide: '.slide',
    slideHed: '.slidehed',
    nextSlide : '.next',
    prevSlide : '.prev',
    addPagination: false,
    addNav : false,
    speed: 1000 // ms.
  });
});
```

```css
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
   
  .carousel-tabs { clear: both; }
  .carousel-active-tab { color: red; } 
  .carousel-disabled,
  .mr-rotato-disabled { color: #aaa; }

  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
    clear: both;
  }
  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs li {
      display: inline-block; 
      padding: 0 2px;
  }
  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs a {
      background: #ddd;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 10px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      width: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .ie .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs li,
  .ie .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs a { 
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs .carousel-active-tab a {
    background: #777;
  }

  .events {
    font: normal 11px/1.4 arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  
.gallery-items { font-size: 0; }

.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: height 500ms ease;
  transition: height 500ms ease;
}

.gallery-expander {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: max-height 500ms ease;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease;
}

.gallery-contents { position: relative; }

.gallery-contents:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-width 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: border-bottom-width 500ms ease;
  transition: border-bottom-width 500ms ease;
}

.gallery-item.active .gallery-contents:after { border-bottom-width: 30px; }

body {
  font-family: 'Nanum Barun Gothic';
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #555;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-item {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail > img {
  position: absolute;
}

.gallery-item .title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.gallery-contents:after { border-bottom-color: #F6F3ED; }

.gallery-expander { background: #F6F3ED; }

.gallery-expander-contents {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

.gallery-expander-contents { width: 640px; }
}
@media (max-width: 639px) {

.gallery-expander-contents { width: 100%; }
}

.gallery-expander-contents:after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col {
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col { width: 310px; }
}
@media (max-width: 639px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col {
  float: none;
  padding: 25px 20px 0;
  width: auto;
}
}

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col + div.col { margin-left: 40px; }
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col + div.col { margin-left: 20px; }
}
@media (max-width: 639px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col + div.col { margin-left: 0px; }
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.title {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #D28A3C;
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.contents {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #BCB098;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BCB098;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #797262;
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.image > img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/11407514532/jquery-imagelistexpander.js"></script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/43702110263/plugin.js"></script>

<div class="slidewrap" data-autorotate="5000">
  <ul class="slidecontrols">
   <li><a href="#sliderName" class="next">Next</a></li>
   <li><a href="#sliderName" class="prev">Prev</a></li>
   
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="slider" id="sliderName">
   <li class="slide"> 
    <ul class="gallery-items" style="width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="slide"> 
    <ul class="gallery-items" style="width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best fix in the world, but it works. 
if next/prev is clicked, "click the "close" button" 
I hope its useful to you.

```js
(function(global, $){
  $('.gallery-items').imagelistexpander({
    prefix: "gallery-"
  });
})(this, jQuery)


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slidewrap').carousel({
    slider: '.slider',
    slide: '.slide',
    slideHed: '.slidehed',
    nextSlide : '.next',
    prevSlide : '.prev',
    addPagination: false,
    addNav : false,
    speed: 1000 // ms.
  });
});


$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".close").click();
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
    $(".close").click();
});
```

```css
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
   
  .carousel-tabs { clear: both; }
  .carousel-active-tab { color: red; } 
  .carousel-disabled,
  .mr-rotato-disabled { color: #aaa; }

  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
    clear: both;
  }
  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs li {
      display: inline-block; 
      padding: 0 2px;
  }
  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs a {
      background: #ddd;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 10px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      width: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .ie .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs li,
  .ie .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs a { 
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .slidewrap2 .carousel-tabs .carousel-active-tab a {
    background: #777;
  }

  .events {
    font: normal 11px/1.4 arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  
.gallery-items { font-size: 0; }

.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: height 500ms ease;
  transition: height 500ms ease;
}

.gallery-expander {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: max-height 500ms ease;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease;
}

.gallery-contents { position: relative; }

.gallery-contents:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-width 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: border-bottom-width 500ms ease;
  transition: border-bottom-width 500ms ease;
}

.gallery-item.active .gallery-contents:after { border-bottom-width: 30px; }

body {
  font-family: 'Nanum Barun Gothic';
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #555;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-item {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail > img {
  position: absolute;
}

.gallery-item .title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.gallery-contents:after { border-bottom-color: #F6F3ED; }

.gallery-expander { background: #F6F3ED; }

.gallery-expander-contents {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

.gallery-expander-contents { width: 640px; }
}
@media (max-width: 639px) {

.gallery-expander-contents { width: 100%; }
}

.gallery-expander-contents:after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col {
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col { width: 310px; }
}
@media (max-width: 639px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col {
  float: none;
  padding: 25px 20px 0;
  width: auto;
}
}

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col + div.col { margin-left: 40px; }
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col + div.col { margin-left: 20px; }
}
@media (max-width: 639px) {

.gallery-expander-contents > div.col + div.col { margin-left: 0px; }
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.title {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #D28A3C;
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.contents {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #BCB098;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BCB098;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #797262;
}

.gallery-expander-contents div.image > img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/11407514532/jquery-imagelistexpander.js"></script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/43702110263/plugin.js"></script>

<div class="slidewrap" data-autorotate="5000">
  <ul class="slidecontrols">
   <li><a href="#sliderName" class="next" >Next</a></li>
   <li><a href="#sliderName" class="prev">Prev</a></li>
   
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="slider" id="sliderName">
   <li class="slide"> 
    <ul class="gallery-items" style="width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="slide"> 
    <ul class="gallery-items" style="width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li class="gallery-item">
     <div class="gallery-contents">
       <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-expander">
       <div class="gallery-expander-contents">
      <div class="gallery-trigger-close close">x</div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="title">Gallery Item</div>
        <div class="contents"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Cool! At least you solved my problem, I should think about this way to do that. Thank you so much :)